# Set first calendrical ocurrence of a date as numeric "1" and then move on day by day

Tags: r, date, dplyr, transform, panel

My dataset looks like this:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), dateday = c("2015-04-08","2015-05-08","2015-05-10","2015-06-28","2015-09-01","2015-09-02","2015-09-03","2015-10-11"), points = c(20,80,140,230,40,60,98,102))

game_data
  player    dateday points
1      1 2015-04-08     20
2      1 2015-05-08     80
3      1 2015-05-10    140
4      1 2015-06-28    230
5      2 2015-09-01     40
6      2 2015-09-02     60
7      2 2015-09-03     98
8      2 2015-10-11    102
```

I want to have a dataset that has one observation for each user for every dateday with an observation, starting with the first dateday entry for this user and call it "1" and then count on day by day.

It should look like this (hope I counted right...)

```
game_data_new <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), dateday = c(1,2,4,53,1,2,3,41), points = c(20,80,140,230,40,60,98,102))

game_data_new
  player dateday points
1      1       1     20
2      1       2     80
3      1       4    140
4      1      53    230
5      2       1     40
6      2       2     60
7      2       3     98
8      2      41    102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple with `dplyr` package. Convert `dateday` to a `Date` object which supports subtracting two dates to get the time difference in days, then get the day difference from day 0 for each player and add 1.

```
library(dplyr)
game_data_new <- game_data %>% 
  mutate(dateday = as.Date(dateday)) %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  mutate(dateday = 1 + as.numeric(dateday - min(dateday)))
```

Answer (score 1):

base solution:

```
game_data$dateday <- 1 + as.numeric(ave(game_data$dateday, game_data$player, FUN = function(days)c(0, diff(as.Date(days, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))))
#[1]  1 31  3 50  1  2  2 39
```

---

data: [stringsAsFactors](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/)

```
game_data <- data.frame(
    player = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
    dateday = c("2015-04-08","2015-05-08","2015-05-10","2015-06-28","2015-09-01","2015-09-02","2015-09-03","2015-10-11"),
    points = c(20,80,140,230,40,60,98,102),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```